# Trying to fetch data from Google Sheets using Google script and displaying on web page having horizontal tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to fetch data based on office name from a Google Sheet and displayed on an HTML page where the office name is selected using a horizontal tab.

The HTML code is displaying fine, but no data is fetched. I can't pinpoint the problem. It is my first time with google scripts and web development.

```
function doGet(){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
   }

  function fetchRushIv(officeName){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var currSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('OG_Database');
 currSheet.activate();

  var table;
     var data = currSheet.getRange(5, 1, currSheet.getLastRow(), 
 currSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  table = "<table id='Rush IV' border='1' style = 'width:100%' 
  padding:10px>";
  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
   var compar=data[i][0];
   if(compar=="Office Name" || compar===officeName){
         table+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<data[1].length;j++){
      table += "<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>";
       }
      table += "</tr>";
       }
       else{
        return 0;
        }

       }
       table += "</table>"

      return table ;
       }
```

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <base target="_top" />
    <script>
      src = "main.js";
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial;
      }

      /* Style the tab */
      .tab {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }

      /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
      .tab button {
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
      }

      /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
      .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }

      /* Create an active/current tablink class */
      .tab button.active {
        background-color: #ccc;
      }

      /* Style the tab content */
      .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
        animation: fadeEffect 1s;
      }

      /* Fade in tabs */
      @-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }

      @keyframes fadeEffect {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
      /*style the header*/
      header {
        background-color: #008080;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: white;
      }

      /*define the second column containing the data area.*/
      dataArea {
        float: left;
        background-color: #fff8dc;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 20px;
        color: #000;
      }

      /*style the footer*/
      footer {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #008080;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
      }

      /*Add responsive layout for the compensation of using on smaller 
screens,i.e.,
     *the two columns will stack up on each other in smaller sized screens.
     */
      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        nav,
        dataArea {
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(failed)
        .withSuccessHandler(displayData)
        .fetchRushIv();

      function getData(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }

      function displayData(table) {
        document.getElementById("customers").innerHTML = table;
      }
      function failed(e) {
        alert("error=" + e);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h4>Sample Data Fetching</h4></header>
    <div class="tab">
      <button
        class="tablinks"
        onclick="getData(event,'Beaumont') google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failed).withSuccessHandler(displayData).fetchRushIv('Beaumont')"
      >
        Beaumont
      </button>
      <button
        class="tablinks"
        onclick="getData(event,'Crosby') google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failed).withSuccessHandler(displayData).fetchRushIv('Crosby')"
      >
        Crosby
      </button>
      <button
        class="tablinks"
        onclick="getData(event,'Splendora') google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failed).withSuccessHandler(displayData).fetchRushIv('Splendora')"
      >
        Splendora
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="content " class="tabcontent">
      <h3>The data Table for the Selected Office</h3>
      <table id="customers" style="width: 100%;"></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot understand about ``no data is fetched.``. Can you provide the information of it? For example, I think that the reason that the table is not displayed when HTML is loaded is ``display: none;`` at ``.tabcontent`` of style. And could you confirm whether the returned values from ``fetchRushIv()`` is what you want?

Comment: No data fetched,i.e., when on the HTML page i click one of the elements in the horizontal tab the data is not displayed. So I'm guessing either the data is not being fetched from the "fetchRushIv()" function or HTML is unable to display for some reason. Tried removing the display:none from code still had no effect.

Comment: @ruben thanks yes the diplay="none" was giving a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys the issue related to inability to display has been resolved and here is the code.

```
function fetchRushIv(officeName){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('OG_Database');
  currSheet.activate();
    var data = currSheet.getRange(5, 1, currSheet.getLastRow(), 
currSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

 var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid #000;padding:5px;}</style> 
 <table>";;
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       if(data[i][0]=="Office Name" || data[i][0]==officeName){
         html+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<data[1].length;j++){
      html += "<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>";
      }
      html+= "</tr>";
}

}
html += "</table>"

  return html ;
}
```

The html portion with the error corrected is as follows:

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
   google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failed).
withSuccessHandler(displayData).fetchRushIv(cityName);
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

 } 

function displayData(table){
document.getElementById('customers').innerHTML=table;
}

function failed(e){
alert("error:"+e);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function fetchRushIv(officeName){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('OG_Database');
  var data=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid #000;padding:5px;}</style><table>"; 
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0]=="Office Name" || data[i][0]==officeName){//I had trouble figuring out what you were doing here so this may be wrong
      html+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
        html+="<td>"+data[i][j]+"</td>";
      }
      html+="</tr>";
    }
  }
  html+="</table>";
  return html;
}
```

This is a lot simpler version of your html.  Get this working first and you can add the rest of the styles later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){//this will run as soon as your DOM loads and that should load your table
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
         document.getElementById('customers').innerHTML=hl;
       })
      .fetchRushIv();

    }) 
   console.log('MyCode');
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id="customers"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

You will still have to test and debug but I think it's a little closer to working. I hope you know how to use the console.log to help you debug the code.

- [Read Support Page for Debugging Help](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: if(data[i][0]=="Office Name" || data[i][0]==officeName)

Here I'm trying to compare the first value of the cell of each row to the "officeName" parameter passed by the calling function in the HTML page. I have a strong feeling this is where the problem is.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake with my google script code.(I was not declaring the if() statement properly)